# How to add controlling and dependent picklist values in apex test class

Tags: apex

I have written apex code to get the controlling field values and corresponding field values but to test that I need to add some values in both controlling and dependent fields and map them in the test class. Most of the posts tell how to get get the mapped values but they dont say how to add the values and map them.

Below is the sample code:

```
public static List<statusResponse> GetDependentOptions(String pObjName, String pControllingFieldName, String pDependentFieldName){
        Map<String,List<String>> objResults = new Map<String,List<String>>();
        //get the string to sobject global map
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> objGlobalMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        if (!objGlobalMap.containsKey(pObjName))
            return null;
        //get the type being dealt with
        Schema.SObjectType pType = objGlobalMap.get(pObjName);
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objFieldMap = pType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        //verify field names
        if (!objFieldMap.containsKey(pControllingFieldName) || !objFieldMap.containsKey(pDependentFieldName))
            return null;     
        //get the control values   
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ctrl_ple = objFieldMap.get(pControllingFieldName).getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
        //get the dependent values
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> dep_ple = objFieldMap.get(pDependentFieldName).getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
        //iterate through the values and get the ones valid for the controlling field name
        Bitset objBitSet = new Bitset();
        //set up the results
        for(Integer pControllingIndex=0; pControllingIndex<ctrl_ple.size(); pControllingIndex++){           
            //get the pointer to the entry
            Schema.PicklistEntry ctrl_entry = ctrl_ple[pControllingIndex];
            //get the label
            String pControllingLabel = ctrl_entry.getLabel();
            //create the entry with the label
            objResults.put(pControllingLabel,new List<String>());
        }
        //cater for null and empty
         objResults.put('',new List<String>());
         objResults.put(null,new List<String>());
        //check the dependent values
        for(Integer pDependentIndex=0; pDependentIndex<dep_ple.size(); pDependentIndex++){          
            //get the pointer to the dependent index
            Schema.PicklistEntry dep_entry = dep_ple[pDependentIndex];
            //get the valid for
            String pEntryStructure = JSON.serialize(dep_entry);                
            TPicklistEntry objDepPLE = (TPicklistEntry)JSON.deserialize(pEntryStructure, TPicklistEntry.class);
            //if valid for is empty, skip
            if (objDepPLE.validFor==null || objDepPLE.validFor==''){
                continue;
            }
            //iterate through the controlling values
            for(Integer pControllingIndex=0; pControllingIndex<ctrl_ple.size(); pControllingIndex++){    
                if (objBitSet.testBit(objDepPLE.validFor,pControllingIndex)){                   
                    //get the label
                    String pControllingLabel = ctrl_ple[pControllingIndex].getLabel();
                    objResults.get(pControllingLabel).add(objDepPLE.label);
                }
            }
        }

        List<statusResponse> response = new List<statusResponse>();
        Set<String> contFields = objResults.keySet();
        for(string contField : contFields){
            statusResponse responseRecord = new statusResponse(contField, objResults.get(contField));
            response.add(responseRecord);
        }
        System.debug('response: '+response);
        return response;
        //return objResults;
    }

    public class TPicklistEntry{
        public string active {get;set;}
        public string defaultValue {get;set;}
        public string label {get;set;}
        public string value {get;set;}
        public string validFor {get;set;}
        public TPicklistEntry(){

        }
    }

    global class statusResponse{
         global List<String> dependentFieldValues;
         global String controllingFieldLabel;
         global statusResponse(String cleFieldLabel, List<String> dpFields){
            controllingFieldLabel = cleFieldLabel;
            dependentFieldValues = dpFields;   
        }
    }

    public class Bitset{
        public Map<String,Integer> AlphaNumCharCodes {get;set;}
        public Map<String, Integer> Base64CharCodes { get; set; }
        public Bitset(){
            LoadCharCodes();
        }
        //Method loads the char codes
        private void LoadCharCodes(){
            AlphaNumCharCodes = new Map<String,Integer>{
                'A'=>65,'B'=>66,'C'=>67,'D'=>68,'E'=>69,'F'=>70,'G'=>71,'H'=>72,'I'=>73,'J'=>74,
                'K'=>75,'L'=>76,'M'=>77,'N'=>78,'O'=>79,'P'=>80,'Q'=>81,'R'=>82,'S'=>83,'T'=>84,
                'U'=>85,'V'=> 86,'W'=>87,'X'=>88,'Y'=>89,'Z'=>90    
            };
            Base64CharCodes = new Map<String, Integer>();
            //lower case
            Set<String> pUpperCase = AlphaNumCharCodes.keySet();
            for(String pKey : pUpperCase){
                //the difference between upper case and lower case is 32
                AlphaNumCharCodes.put(pKey.toLowerCase(),AlphaNumCharCodes.get(pKey)+32);
                //Base 64 alpha starts from 0 (The ascii charcodes started from 65)
                Base64CharCodes.put(pKey,AlphaNumCharCodes.get(pKey) - 65);
                Base64CharCodes.put(pKey.toLowerCase(),AlphaNumCharCodes.get(pKey) - (65) + 26);
            }
            //numerics
            for (Integer i=0; i<=9; i++){
                AlphaNumCharCodes.put(string.valueOf(i),i+48);
                //base 64 numeric starts from 52
                Base64CharCodes.put(string.valueOf(i), i + 52);
            }
        }
        public Boolean testBit(String pValidFor,Integer n){
            System.debug('pValidFor: '+pValidFor);
            //the list of bytes
            List<Integer> pBytes = new List<Integer>();
            //multiply by 6 since base 64 uses 6 bits
            Integer bytesBeingUsed = (pValidFor.length() * 6)/8;
            //will be used to hold the full decimal value
            Integer pFullValue = 0;
            //must be more than 1 byte
            if (bytesBeingUsed <= 1)
                return false;
            //calculate the target bit for comparison
            Integer bit = 7 - (Math.mod(n,8)); 
            //calculate the octet that has in the target bit
            Integer targetOctet = (bytesBeingUsed - 1) - (n >> bytesBeingUsed); 
            //the number of bits to shift by until we find the bit to compare for true or false
            Integer shiftBits = (targetOctet * 8) + bit;
            //get the base64bytes
            for(Integer i=0;i<pValidFor.length();i++){
                //get current character value
                pBytes.Add((Base64CharCodes.get((pValidFor.Substring(i, i+1)))));
            }
            //calculate the full decimal value
            for (Integer i = 0; i < pBytes.size(); i++)
            {
                Integer pShiftAmount = (pBytes.size()-(i+1))*6;//used to shift by a factor 6 bits to get the value
                pFullValue = pFullValue + (pBytes[i] << (pShiftAmount));
            }
            //& is to set the same set of bits for testing
            //shift to the bit which will dictate true or false
            Integer tBitVal = ((Integer)(Math.Pow(2, shiftBits)) & pFullValue) >> shiftBits;
            return  tBitVal == 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, and welcome to SFSE! If you would be so kind as to [edit] your question to include some sample code that demonstrates what you're trying to do (e.g. what you're testing, and what the test method looks like so far), it'd help us give you a better answer.

Comment: Base 64 char include also the characters + and /. You need to add those characters to the function LoadCharCodes

Answer (score 1):

Modifying picklist values is only possible via the tooling or metadata apis. It's possible to call these APIs from APEX code with some work, but it involves callouts which aren't done in test methods (you can only mock them).

In order to test your code you have a couple options. First, create test fields and set them up so your code can verify the expected result. Second, create a wrapper class for the describe values that feed your code, then feed mock test values into your method to test the result.